# Parametric equations where sin(t) and cos(t) must be rational

Tags: parametric

Suppose there are parametric equations

$$
x(t) = at - h\sin(t)
$$
$$
y(t) = a - h\cos(t)
$$

and it is required that both $\sin(t)$ and $\cos(t)$ should be rational.

What the values of $t$ should be in that case?

Thanks.

Comment: The parametric equations have no bearing in the real question, which is "for what values of $t$ are $\sin t$ and $\cos t$ both rational?". I suspect the answer is $t=k\pi/2$ for integral $k$.

Comment: There are infinitely many, though only multiples of $\pi/2$ are "nice." For there are infinitely many rational solutions of $u^2+v^2=1$.

Comment: Are you missing a $t$ in the equation for $y$?

Comment: I think that is a cycloid and there's not $t$ missing in $y$. Not sure, though.

Comment: @nbubis: it is a cycloid equations and so there is no missing $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question (at least how you wrote it) is really,

> For what values of $t$ are both $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ rational?

Note that if $x$ and $y$ are real numbers with $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, then there exists a real number $t$ such that $x = \cos t$, $y = \sin t$.
Therefore, we want solutions to $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ for $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}$.
For this we let $x = \frac{a}{c}$, $y = \frac{b}{d}$, $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$, with the fractions in reduced form.  Then we get
$$
a^2 d^2 + b^2 c^2 = c^2 d^2 \tag{1}
$$
Let $c = c'k$, $d = d'k$ with $c', d'$ relatively prime.  Then the above gives
$$
a^2 d'^2 + b^2 c'^2 = k^2 c'^2 d'^2
$$
Mod $d'$, we find $b^2 \equiv 0$.
Since $\frac{b}{d}$ was in reduced form, $d' = 1$.
Similarly $c' = 1$.
So we get $c = d = k$.
Then we have, coming back to (1),
$$
a^2 + b^2 = c^2
$$
so $(a,b,c)$ are a [Pythagorean triple](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PythagoreanTriple.html).
In particular they are a primitive Pythagorean triple,
because $(a,c) = (b,c) = 1$.
That means all possible $a, b, c$ (up to sign and switching $a$ and $b$) are given by
$$
(a,b,c) = (2mn, m^2 - n^2, m^2 + n^2)
$$
where $m,n$ are relatively prime and not both odd.
Therefore
for any $a,b,c$ the solution $t$
is given by
$$
t = \pm \cos^{-1}\left(\frac{a}{c}\right) + 2\pi n
= \pm \cos^{-1} \left(\pm \frac{2mn}{m^2 + n^2} \right)
\text{ or }
 \pm \cos^{-1} \left(\pm \frac{m^2 - n^2}{m^2 + n^2} \right)
$$
for some $m,n$.
Unfortunately we cannot in general simplify the $\cos^{-1}$ out of the formula
as far as I know.

Comment: thank you for such a comprehensive answer. One more question: suppose it is given that $\cos(t)$ and $\sin(t)$ are both rational and also $\cos(at)$ and $\sin(at)$, where $a$ is some constant, are both rational too. Does it exist some relation between these two "groups" in terms of $m$ and $n$?

Comment: @user144765 I'll think about that, but really you should ask a new question, and *link back to* this one.  The comments are for clarification of existing answers, not for asking entirely new questions.

Comment: OK, i've done it - [Relation between sin(t)(cos(t)) and sin(at) (cos(at)) when both are rational](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791387/relation-between-sint-cost-and-sinat-cosat-when-both-are)

Answer (score 1):

Take any two integers $m$ and $n$, and then choose $t$ so that $\tan \tfrac12 t= r = m/n$.

Then, using well-known trig identities 
$$
\cos t = \frac{1-r^2}{1+r^2} = \frac{m^2-n^2}{m^2+n^2}  \quad ; \quad
\sin t = \frac{2r}{1+r^2} = \frac{2m}{m^2+n^2}
$$
So $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ are both rational.